# La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Encontré varias preguntas a cerca del mismo problema pero ninguna tiene la solución que requiero, las demás lo hacen con algún tipo de fecha (Datetime).

Estoy desarrollando mi formulario de registro en **ASP.NET MVC** y estoy presentando el siguiente error al momento de guardar en la base de datos en la linea de `ticketExtAppliInput`

> System.FormatException: 'La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato
>   correcto.'

El siguiente es el código de mi controlador

**TicketFormController.cs**

```
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult CreateNewTicket()

        {
            var files = new HttpPostedFileBase[Request.Files.Count];

            var ticketIdAppliInput = Request.Form["ticketIdAppliInput"];
            var ticketNameAppliInput = Request.Form["ticketNameAppliInput"];
            var ticketEmailAppliInput = Request.Form["ticketEmailAppliInput"];
            var ticketExtAppliInput = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["ticketExtAppliInput"]);
            var ticketPhoneAppliInput = Request.Form["ticketPhoneAppliInput"];
            var ticketAreaAppliInput = Request.Form["ticketAreaAppliInput"];
            var ticketLocationAppliInput = Request.Form["ticketLocationAppliInput"];
            var ticketSubjectInput = Request.Form["ticketSubjectInput"];
            var ticketDescrInput = Request.Form["ticketDescrInput"];
            var ticketPriorityInput = Request.Form["ticketPriorityInput"];
            var ticketServiceInput = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["ticketServiceInput"]);
            var ticketSubServiceInput = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["ticketSubServiceInput"]);
            var ticketCategoryInput = Request.Form["ticketCategoryInput"];
            var ticketOriginInput = Request.Form["ticketOriginInput"];    
            var area = Session["area"] ?? Request.Form["ticketAreaInput"];
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Posiblemente requiero hacer alguna validación con este campo cuando este vació y no se envié a la base de datos, el campo `ticketExtAppliInput` es de tipo `int`, pero no estoy seguro de como hacerla, si esa puede ser la solución pueden indicarme como arreglarlo si no cual seria la solución correcta

Comment: Me late que tienes un null o un string.

Comment: @fredyfx correcto es un null pero necesito hacer la validación, no siempre ese campo se va a enviar null a la base de datos, depende de ciertas reglas

Comment: ya tienes la respuesta, primero verifica que sea diferente de null, luego procede a hacer un try parse a int y si falla, le asignas un valor by default o un mensaje al usuario, esto depende de las reglas de negocio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta verificando si el valor puede ser convertido a `int` utilizando [`int.TryParse()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8) que retorna `false` si el valor no pudo ser convertido:

```
int ticketExtAppliInput = 0;

if(int.TryParse(Request.Form["ticketExtAppliInput"], out ticketExtAppliInput) == false)
{
  // el valor no pudo ser convertido a entero
}
```