# Error no se puede convertir de 'out string' a 'out int'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estoy desarrollando mi primer formulario de registro en **ASP.NET MVC** y estoy presentando el siguiente error

> Argumento 2: no se puede convertir de 'out string' a 'out int'

```
var ticketPriorityInput = "ALTO";

        if (int.TryParse(Request.Form["ticketPriorityInput"], out ticketPriorityInput) == false)
        {

        }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

`ticketPriorityInput` es de tipo `string`

Esto lo hago porque necesito validar que cuando se envié a guardar el campo `ticketPriorityInput` lo guarde por defecto con la cadena "ALTO", pueden indicarme como es la mejor manera de hacerlo o como puedo solucionarlo

Comment: `int.TryParse`, integer != string

Comment: @fredyfx cual es la forma correcta de hacerlo con un dato de tipo string

Comment: Request.Form["ticketPriorityInput"] == null ? valoPorfecto : Request.Form["ticketPriorityInput"]

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/287587/822

Comment: si estás comparando un par de strings, basta con `==`. O si deseas hacer algo más detallado: `String.Equals(valor1, valor2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` donde valor1 y valor2 son strings

Comment: Puedes agregarlo detalladamente en forma de pregunta así me confundes

Comment: Primero intenta, luego si la confusión sigue, procedo a responder.

Comment: @fredyfx Me confirmas si asi es la forma correcta de agregarlo `var ticketPriorityInput = Request.Form["ticketPriorityInput"] == null ? "ALTO" : Request.Form["ticketPriorityInput"];`

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97795/discussion-between-fredyfx-and-sebastian-salazar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En base a lo conversado, este es el código que estás buscando:

```
var prioridadDelTicket = Request.Form["ticketPriorityInput"];
var ticketPriorityInputByDefault = "ALTO";

if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(prioridadDelTicket)){
   prioridadDelTicket = ticketPriorityInputByDefault;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

El error radica básicamente en que la variable de salida del método TryParse de int es de tipo int, pero se le está pasando una variable de tipo string.

Si se está haciendo uso de C# 7, se puede optar por el "Modificador de parámetro Out": https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier

```
if (int.TryParse(Request.Form["ticketPriorityInput"], out  var ticketPriorityInput))
        {
//Code...
        }
```

Ahora, si lo que se quiere es que por defecto ticketPriorityInput tenga el valor "ALTO", no tiene sentido que se haga un intento de parseo a int.

**UPDATE:**

Según tu último comentario, creo que podrías hacerlo de esta forma:

```
        var ticketPriorityInput = Request.Form.AllKeys.Contains("ticketPriorityInput") 
                                && Request.Form[ticketPriorityInput] != null ?
                                Request.Form[ticketPriorityInput] : "ALTO";
```

Comment: Lo que requiero es que `ticketPriorityInput` tenga el valor "ALTO" por defecto, teniendo en cuenta que `ticketPriorityInput` es de tipo string y no tengo necesidad de parseo a int, como lograría hacerlo

Comment: Coloqué un update con una alternativa (pueden haber muchas formas de hacer lo que quieres). No olvides marcar la respuesta si te fue de ayuda.